# Do edit suggestions make community wiki superfluous?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

The FAQ says that Community Wiki works:

> by transferring ownership of the post
>   from the original author to the
>   community. They make the post easier
>   to edit and maintain by a wider group
>   of users, but they do not contribute
>   to any user's reputation.

But using the new edit suggestion system, everyone can edit. It's no longer true that community wiki makes a post easier to edit.

Does community wiki still serve a function?

What are good examples of community wiki mode doing what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Minor point: Community Wiki posts are easier to edit, for those with 100 or more rep, in that suggested edits may be rejected, or delayed waiting for approval.

Comment: Excellent question, I hadn't thought of it that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some ways, I think it does. Generally, I would decline a suggested edit to a post that edited the actual content of the post—I usually only accept formatting and grammar cleanups. However, CW answers tend to be for answers contributed by the community. For example, if someone listed a bunch of books in a regular answer, I would decline a suggested edit that added another book because the OP hadn't recommended that one. With CW, however, there is no OP—the books are collectively recommended by the community.